# git source control checkout ignored

Tags: git, version-control, terminal

I'm developing an app in XCode and I'm using git repositories via terminal. All changes are committed and now I want to revert to my last commit, but, however, when I try to 'git checkout 10f3592' it says 'HEAD is now at 10f3592...' but in the XCode my source files are not changed. It seems like git is ignoring my command. What should I do? Does anyone has encountered a behavior like this before? I have only 1 branch btw. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `git commit 10f3592` does?! Is `10f3592` your last commit? If so, then checking it out won't change anything.

Comment: @Biffen a typo, I just edited now. I meant checkout*

Comment: So are you checking out your last commit? And you expect that to ‘revert’ it? Seems like the best thing for you to do is read some Git documentation/tutorial.

Comment: @Biffen Now I noticed the head is detached in my branch. How to fix that?

Comment: By checking out something else. But really, do yourself a favour and read something.

Comment: @KirilShishkoski Checkout your branch via `git checkout yourBranch`, then undo the commit using an appropriate method.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen * (HEAD detached at 8422ab4)
  master... So I have to do git checkout master. After doing it, will I lose 8422ab4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `git checkout 10f3592` just checks out the branch in a detached head state at commit `10f3592`.  It does not actually change the state of your branch.

If you want to literally `git revert` commit `10f3592`, then use `git revert`:

```
git revert 10f3592
```

This will instruct Git to make a *new* commit on the top of your branch which effectively undoes everything which commit `10f3592` did.

But sometimes it isn't so nice to have a revert commit in your history.  One way to avoid this, if you haven't yet pushed your local branch, and no one else has yet seen commit `10f3592`, is to *nuke* that commit via:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: Now I noticed I have a HEAD detached at 10f3592. How to fix the detached head?

Comment: @KirilShishkoski There is nothing to "fix."  Just checkout your branch and follow my answer to remove the commit.